# click event not working on inner tag elements

Tags: javascript, click, stoppropagation

This is the markup that I'm working with

```
<div class="checkout-row__form-column__billing">
  <div class="checkout-row__form-column__billing__title billing-collapse collapse-btn">
     <div class="checkout-row__form-column__billing__title__arrow">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
   <h2>1. Billing Details</h2>
</div>
<div class="checkout-row__form-column__shipping__content shipping-collapse-content collapse-target"></div>
<div class="checkout-row__form-column__shipping">
  <div class="checkout-row__form-column__shipping__title shipping-collapse collapse-btn">
     <div class="checkout-row__form-column__shipping__title__arrow">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
   <h2>2. Shipping Details</h2>
</div>
<div class="checkout-row__form-column__shipping__content shipping-collapse-content collapse-target"></div>
```

All this markup is wrapped in `div` with a class of `checkout-row__form-column`.
So, I'm grabbing the parent wrapper, on click I match target with `.collapse-btn`. and then I do class toggle on the sibling which is `.collapse-target`. Works great except on issue, that I can't get past. If I click on the inner element, the event doesn't happen.

Here is my js

```
parent = document.querySelector('.checkout-row__form-column');
    parent.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
      if (e.target.matches('.collapse-btn')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        
        e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
      }
    });
```

With these code I am able to toggle classes if I don't click on `i` element or `h2`. How can I write my JavaScript that event will be fired if I click anywhere inside the `e.target`.

Any help is much appreciated fellow commarades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only checks if the `event.target` is the `.collapse-btn` element or not. You also need to check if the clicked element is a descendant element of the `.collapse-btn` element.

To achieve the desired result, you can use the two conditions to check if the `event.target` is the `.collapse-btn` or any of its descendant. To check for descendant elements, use the universal selector `*`.

```
parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (
       e.target.matches('.collapse-btn') || 
       e.target.matches('.collapse-btn *')
  ) {
     // code
  }
});
```

#### Demo

Following snippet shows an example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.container');

parent.addEventListener('click', e => {  
  if (
      e.target.matches('.collapse-btn') ||
      e.target.matches('.collapse-btn *') 
  ) {
    parent.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.container.active {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.collapse-btn {
  background: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.collapse-btn span {
  background: #fc3;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="collapse-btn">
    <span>Click</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also put the selectors in an array and then use `.some()` method to check if `event.target` matches ay of the selector in the array.

```
const selectors = ['.collapse-btn', '.collapse-btn *'];

parent.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (selectors.some(s => e.target.matches(s))) {
    // code
  }
});
```

#### Demo

Following snippet shows an example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.container');

parent.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const selectors = ['.collapse-btn', '.collapse-btn *'];

  if (selectors.some(s => e.target.matches(s))) {
    parent.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.container.active {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.collapse-btn {
  background: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.collapse-btn span {
  background: #fc3;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="collapse-btn">
    <span>Click</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Alternative Solution

Instead of using the `.matches()` method, use the combination of [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and  [`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) methods to check if the `event.target` is the `.collapse-btn` element or is a child element of the `.collapse-btn` element.

For this to work, you need to do two steps:

1. You first need to get the `.collapse-btn` that is the closest ancestor of the `event.target`.
2. After that, you need to check if the `event.target` is a descendant of the button selected in step 1.

**Code:**

```
parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   const targetCollapseBtn = e.target.closest('.collapse-btn');

   if (targetCollapseBtn && targetCollapseBtn.contains(e.target)) {
       ...
   }
});
```

If `event.target` is the `.collapse-btn` itself, then

```
e.target.closest('.collpase-btn')
```

will return the `e.target`, i.e. `.collapse-btn` and

```
targetCollapseBtn.contains(e.target)
```

will also return true because `.contains()` method returns true even if the node passed to it as an argument is the same node as the one on which `.contains()` method was called.

So using `.closest()` and `.contains()` methods in this way covers both the use cases, i.e. when `.collapse-btn` is clicked or when any of its descendant element is clicked.

#### Demo

Following snippet shows a simple example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.container');

parent.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const targetCollapseBtn = e.target.closest('.collapse-btn');

  if (targetCollapseBtn && targetCollapseBtn.contains(e.target)) {
    parent.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.container.active {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.collapse-btn {
  background: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.collapse-btn span {
  background: #fc3;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="collapse-btn">
    <span>Click</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yousaf, thanks for your answers, the last approach did work!